# What is the seasonality of a data stream and how to use it to estimate the stream attributes?

Tags: definition, real-time

I am trying to understand what is the rigorous definition of [seasonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality) is, but couldn't find it. Is it a mathematical tool at all?

I need to analyze a stream coming from one source and be able to estimate the data coming from the source. I need to take into account the seasonality of the data and try to prototype the source behavior. let's say the stream is `(time, data)` tuples.

Comment: Your question is kind of vague (and the edit makes it also very broad). Further, what's "source stream characterization"? If seasonality is used in the context of a model I'd certainly say it was mathematical. For example, one form of seasonal time series model is [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9)

Comment: I don't think the edit makes this any clearer (at least for me). What stream and source are you talking about?

Comment: source is an endpoint sends data, could be `ip` address, and the stream is raw data. It can be whatever it is an abstract question, how to learn a stream and being able to estimate it or extrapolate it. @rocinante

Comment: Ok. Well, I am not sure what degree of rigor you are looking for in your definition. If you are talking about say, the data that users submit to this website, there is a seasonal component to it, if we assume that most/all users live in the same time zone. The site is active during the day, but it is not as active during the night because people are sleeping. People also go on vacation and write exams, so traffic varies according to that too. If you want to analyze traffic, you have to take into account these differences before you can say that more people are using the site than before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no seasonality is not a mathematical tool. However, it can be expressed using mathematical tools. Different data can have different seasonalities, depending on the flow of the data. Seasonality can be an inherent component of the data you are analyzing.

Seasonality, if it is part of your data should be included in your model in order to make accurate forecasts.

Time series might have a trend component, a seasonal component or both.

For instance a model that represents a seasonal event of period 12 (every 12 months) with peaks in June and lows in January and no trend might be modeled as

```
   X(t) = s(t) + Y(t)
```

with t being time, Y(t) random noise, s(t) being the periodic function that represents the seasonal component with period 12. Where s(t) could be modeled by  Fourier functions.

You can look into any introductory book on time series to learn more on forecasting,
but let me suggest some good books that use R, which in my opinion makes it easier to understand and learn by doing.

For a quick intro check out [A Little Book of R for Time Series](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it's free!

For a more in depth understanding (and somewhat expensive) you can look into one of these:

Introductory Time Series with R. Paul Cowpertwait and Andrew Metcalfe

Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R. Jonathan Cryer and Kung-Sik Chan

Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples. Robert Shumway and David Stoffer